# Replacement word for FLAGS code analysis warning

Tags: c#, code-analysis

I am writing C# code with Microsoft All Rules set in Code analysis properties. Now I have a struct whose name is NodeFlag. Upon running code analysis it gives me CA1726 error.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182258.aspx

It basically says that I should remove the word Flag from struct. And now my question is what should I write. What are good words to replace with Flag. I was thinking to suppress these warnings but this NodeFlag is used in many places.

**Update:**
Here is the struct

```
struct NodeFlag
{
    bool IsValid;
    bool IsInsideGrid;
    bool ....
    ....
    double XCoordinate;
    double YCoordinate;

    override functions for ==, !=, Equals
}
```

Comment: Is there any code? I would say flag is more relevant to `Enum`s.

Comment: well, what *is* this `NodeFlag`? what does it *mean*? what does it *represent*? renaming the struct itself is pretty easy (unless you are using `BinaryFormatter` anywhere, and need to use existing serialized data): a simple `F2` usually fixes most places. Perhaps you could *show us* what `NodeFlag` looks like, so we can offer an informed opinion

Comment: struct contains some bool and integers, renaming is not a problem. Problem is that what should I rename it to, Replacement for FLAG?,

Comment: @Faisal a replacement for FLAG is: what this thing actually **is**. I'm guessing it doesn't represent an government or organisation's emblem, in a form that can be printed onto a sheet of cloth and flown on a pole in the breeze

Comment: Actually I am translating a code from C++ to C#. In C++ name of struct is NodeFlag, so I am looking for a good proper name in C#.

Comment: @MarcGravell I updated question. Added the struct.

Comment: I think Information will be a good replacement for Flag, what do you think?,

Comment: @FaisalHafeez I think "Information" is not a good name because everything computers deal with is information.

Answer (score 0):

If the name "Flag" has already been chosen and used in existing code or APIs, stick with that and disable the warning.

---

It looks like this is an X, Y Cartesian coordinate?  Then how about calling it `NodePoint`, `NodeCoordinates`, or `NodeLocation`?

Comment: I did that, but object of this structure is made in many classes, which means I have to suppress a lot of warnings, I can change its name, there is no issue in that. But replacement of FLAG?,